# Can I use two 0.25 W resistors to get a 0.5 W resistor?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

How do I make a \$220 \Omega\$ 0.5 W resistor using 0.25 W resistors (no matter what the value of the resistors). All I know is

\$V = I \times R\$ (which we call Ohm's law)

\$P = I \times V\$ (sometimes called Watt's law)

Comment: Parallel two 440 ohm 0.25w

Comment: You can use two 440 Ohm parallel of 0.25 or two 110 Ohm series of 0.25

Answer (score 3):

**If this is a homework question**

Then there are two answers, either:

1. Two 440 Ohm resistors in parallel. Each resistor gets the full voltage, but half the current, so half the power.

or:

2. Two 110 ohm resistors in series. Each resistor carries the full current, but only sees half the voltage, so half the power.

**If you are designing something**

You don't want to run the resistors near their power limit, as they will get very hot.  Through hole resistors are  worse than SMD ones in this respect, as they are usually rated assuming they are in free air, but in reality they are usually mounted on a PCB, so don't cool as effectively. So you should aim for a rating well over what you actually plan to use.  If you're going to be dissipating 1/2W in 1/4W resistors, I would suggest four equal resistors in series.

Comment: i really appreciate your help .. am gonna explain more about the project .. its a metal detector with a pulse induction and the problem was at the coil poles it must be an 220 ohm 0.5w and the battery was 12 v 70 mA
this is a shimatic for the project http://imgur.com/53Uiq7Y

Comment: You better post a new topic with these new specification ;)

Comment: As it happens 110 ohms is a standard value while 440 ohms is not.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I see two solutions to your problem :

**1. Use two 440 ohm resistors in parallel**

Since current will split equally across the two resistors, the power is divided by two for each resistor.

$$P = Ri^2$$ with R = 220 ohm and i the current to have P = 0.5W

Resistor's value have to double in order to have the same resulting resistance and the current is divided by two. 
$$R1 = 2*R$$$$i1 = i/2$$ $$P1 = 2*R*(i/2)^2 = R*i^2 / 2 = P/2$$

As you can see, resistors will "share" equally the power.

**2. Use two 110 ohm resistors in series**

By using two resistors in series, the power is also split equally across both resistor.

The current passing through each resistor is still the same but resistor's value is twice lower, so the dissipated power for each resistor is also divided by two.

Comment: Two series resistors will also work

Comment: Yes you are right ! I'll complet my answer later with exemple

Comment: I just update my post

Answer (score 0):

Use \$ 4 \times 220~\Omega \$ for \$1 \times 220~\Omega\$ at four times the power rating.

Put them in series/parallel, two in parallel - in series with - two in parallel.  That is $$ {220~\Omega \times 220~\Omega\over{2\times 220~\Omega}} = 110~\Omega$$ in series with \$ 110~\Omega\$.

Comment: For this to qualify as an answer please fully explain how to arrange the resistors. This answer does not meet minimum quality standards.